# java beginner - cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and trying to create a program that recieves input numbers in terminal, and will continuously ask for a new numbers until 0 is entered. After 0 has been entered I want the program to summarize all of the numbers and plus them together. But when I try to compile the program I get this error:

[image]

Heres the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumTall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tallscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tall = 0;
        int tall1;

        System.out.println("Write a number:");
        tall1 = Integer.parseInt(tallscanner.nextLine());

        while(tall1 > 0) {
            System.out.println("Write another number:");
            tall1 = Integer.parseInt(tallscanner.nextLine());
            int tall2 = tall + tall1;
        }
        if(tall1 == 0) {
            System.out.println(tall2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot find symbol means that the variable you're trying to access doesn't exist in this case. The reason for this is that your variable `tall2` is defined inside the `while` loop while you're accessing it outside.

Comment: Format your code properbly and you will see what's wrong

Comment: Take a look at accepted answer in duplicate question (you may need to reload this page to see it) and search for examples with "scope" problem.

Comment: If you use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ rather than a simple text-editor and the command-line, then these problems would show themselves before you attempted to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `tall2` in  `while` block declare it outside while. it will stick to that block only in your case it belong to while block but you are trying to access that variavle  `tall2` out side while that's the reason you can see that error. hope it will help you.

I changed the declaration part out side.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumTall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tallscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tall = 0;
        int tall1,tall2;

        System.out.println("Write a number:");
        tall1 = Integer.parseInt(tallscanner.nextLine());

        while(tall1 > 0) {
            System.out.println("Write another number:");
            tall1 = Integer.parseInt(tallscanner.nextLine());
            tall2 = tall + tall1;
        }
        if(tall1 == 0) {
            System.out.println(tall2);
        }
    }
}
```